# "OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException : element not visible", in C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Please help me resolve a problem: "wait" does not work 20 seconds or 30..., the testing runs successfully, but failed when run "Debug Test".
The code is copied below:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "/html/body/form/div[12]/div[1]/div[1]..../ul/li/a")]
private OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement NewMRLink;

//..........
Pages.WaitForElementVisible(Browser.driver, CreateR);
CreateR.Click();
```

==========================

```
public static bool WaitForElementVisible(IWebDriver driver, IWebElement ele)
{
    try
    {
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        wait.Until(d => (bool)(ele as IWebElement).Displayed);
        return true;
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

===================

Comment: i changed to 60 second, when run on .net, it does not wait, then pops up an error

Comment: This is the error, not the one on this Title, OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : Could not find element by: By.XPath: /html/body/form/div[..../div/div/div/div

Comment: Should I changed to "wait.Until(d => (bool)(ele.Displayed));"

Comment: or  wait.Until(d => (ele.Displayed));

Comment: That is Okay, I am running a unit test on .NET (C#),